# Use column values to create wide format table

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape

I have the following dataframe:

```
class   outcome   count    total
A       TP        5        20
A       FP        5        20
A       TN        5        20
A       FN        5        20
B       TP        10       40
B       FP        10       40
B       TN        10       40
B       FN        10       40
```

Where I essentially want this in  so called wide format i.e.

```
type    TP    FP    TN    FN    total
A       5     5     5     5     20 
B       10    10    10    10    40
```

I can almost get there by doing:

```
> dcast(test,test$outcome ~ test$class)
Using class...outcome...count....total as value column: use value.var to override.
  .  A       FN        5        20  A       FP        5        20  A       TN        5        20  A       TP        5        20
1 .  A       FN        5        20  A       FP        5        20  A       TN        5        20  A       TP        5        20
   B       FN        10       40  B       FP        10       40  B       TN        10       40  B       TP        10       40
1  B       FN        10       40  B       FP        10       40  B       TN        10       40  B       TP        10       40
```

where I now have a column for each outcome type, but I have missing column names, duplicate rows and my wanted column headers (TP,FP,TN,FN) as column values...still.

So also quite far off.

Is this even possible with dcast?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do that with `tidyr` using `spread`:

```
library(tidyr)
df1 <-read.table(text="class   outcome   count    total
A       TP        5        20
A       FP        5        20
A       TN        5        20
A       FN        5        20
B       TP        10       40
B       FP        10       40
B       TN        10       40
B       FN        10       40",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(tidyr)
spread(df1,outcome,count)

  class total FN FP TN TP
1     A    20  5  5  5  5
2     B    40 10 10 10 10
```

And here's the `dcast` solution:

```
dcast(df1, class +total ~ outcome, value.var="count")
  class total FN FP TN TP
1     A    20  5  5  5  5
2     B    40 10 10 10 10
```

Comment: this is awesome. this was exactly what I was looking for and what I thought dcast should be doing. thaknks.

Comment: @brucezepplin I just added the `dcast` solution. I find `gather` easier to understand so that's why I started with that.

Answer (score 0):

Using `reshape` in base R (where `df` is your data frame)

```
reshape(df, idvar = c("class", "total"), timevar = "outcome", direction = "wide")

#  class total count.TP count.FP count.TN count.FN
#1     A    20        5        5        5        5
#5     B    40       10       10       10       10
```